# How to implement classes doing same job?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have some classes doing exact the same job. Only some properties are different.
Should i use interfaces to avoid code rewritten again and again? 
I'm a newbie at object oriented programming so sorry if the question is too easy for stackoverflow.

Could you please help me to make this implemantation in properway, so i dont need to rewrite methods for all classes ?

Here are the sample classes for my case:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }


    public Class1()
    {
        Prop1 = "Class 1 Property 1";
        Prop2 = "Class 1 Property 2";
        Prop2 = "Class 1 Property 3";
    }

    public void Method(string variable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop2);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop3);
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }


    public Class2()
    {
        Prop1 = "Class 2 Property 1";
        Prop2 = "Class 2 Property 2";
        Prop2 = "Class 2 Property 3";
    }

    public void Method(string variable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop2);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop3);
    }
}

public class Class3
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }


    public Class3()
    {
        Prop1 = "Class 3 Property 1";
        Prop2 = "Class 3 Property 2";
        Prop2 = "Class 3 Property 3";
    }

    public void Method(string variable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop2);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop3);
    }
}
```

Comment: A base class, abstract or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely achieve some re-use and avoid DRY.

```
public abstract class Base {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }

    public void Method(string variable) {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop2);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Prop3);
    }
}

public class Class1 : Base {
    public Class1() {
        Prop1 = "Class 1 Property 1";
        Prop2 = "Class 1 Property 2";
        Prop2 = "Class 1 Property 3";
    }
}

public class Class2 : Base {
    public Class2() {
        Prop1 = "Class 2 Property 1";
        Prop2 = "Class 2 Property 2";
        Prop2 = "Class 2 Property 3";
    }
}

public class Class3 : Base {
    public Class3() {
        Prop1 = "Class 3 Property 1";
        Prop2 = "Class 3 Property 2";
        Prop2 = "Class 3 Property 3";
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to inherit base :)

Comment: @Thorarins Thank you, I need more coffee.

Comment: is there a way using interfaces in this situation?